# Shrink widgets if they don't fit into LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Say I have a vertical `LinearLayout` and several `TextView`s in it with `layout_height` set to `wrap_content`.
This way the last TextView becomes clipped at the bottom:
[image: Last view is clipped]

Setting `layout_height="match_parent"` and `layout_weight="1"` for each `TextView` 'solves' this problem:[image: Does fit into the screen]

Unfortunately, this leads to very large intervals between views in `portrait layout`:[image: Large intervals between TextView]

So, is there any way to arrange items on the screen so that:

1. They all fit into the screen
2. If the screen is large, they should be placed one by one without huge spaces between them, having, however, free space at the bottom
   ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the cases where you should use different layout resources for different configurations. For example, based on your example you could have a `layout-land` folder for when the phone is in landscape and in that layout use the xml layout where all the `TextViews` have `layout_weight="1"`. For portrait orientation(and the default layout) you could have in your `layout` folder a layout file like the one from the `layout-land` to which you would add this element after the `TextViews`:

```
 <View        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
```

This empty `View` will "absorb" some of the empty space so you don't have a big gap between the `TextViews`.

The different layout files for different screen could be improved by using further refined layouts for screens of different size(normal, large, very large) combined with different orientations(portrait vs landscape).

Of course, you could write your own layout manager to position the child `TextViews` but this isn't something easy to do.

Comment: All right, thanks for the reply. However it still seems strange to me that such a simple layout requirement cannot be done in a single resource.